# Why do labels exist?

Tags: javascript, labeled-statements

Why do labels exist in javascript?

```
var i = 0;

usefulLabel://why do I exist?
while(i <= 10){
    document.writeln(i);
    i++;
    if(i > 5)
        break;// usefulLabel;
}
```

The above code doesn't appear to need a label at all (it works with or without the commented label name).  And Considering Douglas Crockford has not condemned them entirely:

[Labels](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)

> Statement labels are optional. Only these statements should be
> labeled: while, do, for, switch.

Are they ever considered a good practice to implement?  To me, these things look eerily close to the infamous goto statement in some languages.

Comment: It *is* a `goto` - you are transferring control from inside your loop to a named label. That's exactly what a `goto` does.

Comment: They **are** eerily close to a `goto` and of questionable utility.  Imagine, however that you have three nested loops and you want to break out of them all completely.

Comment: Except for "big" breaks/continues, ew.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to break out of the outermost loop from a nested loop, you need a label.
If you end up needing that, you should consider refactoring the code to make it simpler.  (although that won't always be possible)

Comment: +1 Interesting.  Why don't I see people saying use goto in this case for C#?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: C# does not support this feature (labelled `break` / `continue`)

Answer (score 2):

Yup, they exist for GOTOs and SWITCH statements.  I basically see them used for nothing else, and would never consider labeling a section of code just for the fun of it..

Answer (score 0):

The code sample you provided doesn't use the label at all, as it is not referenced in any place.

Read more about labels here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Statements#label_Statement

Here's the example of breaking the loop:

```
var x = 0;
var z = 0
labelCancelLoops: while (true) {
    console.log("Outer loops: " + x);
    x += 1;
    z = 1;
    while (true) {
        console.log("Inner loops: " + z);
        z += 1;
        if (z === 10 && x === 10) {
            break labelCancelLoops;
        } else if (z === 10) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I would suggest using the labels to the minimum, as they are confusing to read and follow the flow of the execution. Just like the GOTO.